# How to pass two object at a time to the template using Rails Ajax call

Tags: ruby, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I want to pass two object to the template which is going to render after Ajax call using Rails 3.See my below controller file.

> controller/homes_controller.rb

```
class HomesController < ApplicationController
    def home
        @sdf=TSdf.new
        respond_to do |format|
          format.html
          format.js
        end
    end
    def scan_report
        @sdf=TSdf.find_by_Receipt_No(params[:sdf][:Receipt_No])
        @hcsy=THcsy.find_by_Sdp_Id(@sdf.Sdp_Id)

    end
end
```

In the scan_report action from the above file I have created two object to access DB values and using these two object i have ti display data in this below template.

> view/homes/_hcsy_output_table.html.erb

```
<div class="block-title">
        <div class="block-options">
            <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="btn btn-option enable-tooltip" data-toggle="block-collapse" title="Toggle block's content"><i class="fa fa-arrow-up"></i></a>
        </div>
            <h4>Harischandra Sahayata Yojana Form</h4>
    </div>
    <!--1st_total_div-->
    <div class="block-content">
      <div class="block block-themed themed-asphalt">
      <div class="block-title"><h5>Personal Details</h5></div>
            <div class="block-content full">
                    <div class="totalaligndiv">
                      <div class="input-group bmargindiv1 col-md-6 pull-left"><span class="input-group-addon text-left"><div class="leftsidetextwidth">Receipt No :</div></span>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" value= "<%= @sdf.Receipt_No %>"> 
                      </div>
                      <div class="input-group bmargindiv1 col-md-6 pull-left"><span class="input-group-addon text-left"><div class="leftsidetextwidth">Date &amp; Time :</div></span>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" value= "<%= @hcsy.Created_On %>"> 
                      </div>
                      <div class="input-group bmargindiv1 col-md-6 pull-left"><span class="input-group-addon text-left"><div class="leftsidetextwidth">Name of Deceased :</div></span>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Name of Deceased"> 
                      </div>
                      <div class="input-group bmargindiv1 col-md-6 pull-left"> <span class="input-group-addon text-left"><div class="leftsidetextwidth">Mobile No :</div></span>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Mobile No"> 
                      </div>
                      <div class="input-group bmargindiv1 col-md-6 pull-left"><span class="input-group-addon text-left"><div class="leftsidetextwidth">Beneficiary Name :</div></span>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Beneficiary Name"> 
                      </div>
                      <div class="input-group bmargindiv1 col-md-6 pull-left"> <span class="input-group-addon text-left"><div class="leftsidetextwidth">Occupation :</div></span>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Occupation"> 
                      </div>
                      <div class="input-group bmargindiv1 col-md-12 pull-left"> <span class="input-group-addon text-left"><div class="leftsidetextwidth">Relation with Deceased :</div></span>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Relation with Deceased"> 
                      </div>
                      <div class="input-group bmargindiv1 col-md-6 pull-left"> <span class="input-group-addon text-left"><div class="leftsidetextwidth">Address Line - I :</div></span>
                        <textarea name="versions comments" placeholder="Address" class="form-control" rows="3"></textarea>
                      </div>
                      <div class="input-group bmargindiv1 col-md-6 pull-left"> <span class="input-group-addon text-left"><div class="leftsidetextwidth">Address Line - II :</div></span>
                        <textarea name="versions comments" placeholder="Address" class="form-control" rows="3"></textarea>
                      </div>
                      <div class="input-group bmargindiv1 col-md-6 pull-left"> <span class="input-group-addon text-left"><div class="leftsidetextwidth">Village/City :</div></span>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Village/City"> 
                      </div>
                      <div class="input-group bmargindiv1 col-md-6 pull-left"> <span class="input-group-addon text-left"><div class="leftsidetextwidth">Block :</div></span>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Block"> 
                      </div>
                      <div class="input-group bmargindiv1 col-md-6 pull-left"> <span class="input-group-addon text-left"><div class="leftsidetextwidth">District :</div></span>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="District"> 
                      </div>
                      <div class="input-group bmargindiv1 col-md-6 pull-left"> <span class="input-group-addon text-left"><div class="leftsidetextwidth">State :</div></span>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="State"> 
                      </div>
                      <div class="input-group bmargindiv1 col-md-6 pull-left"> <span class="input-group-addon text-left"><div class="leftsidetextwidth">Country :</div></span>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Country"> 
                      </div>
                      <div class="input-group bmargindiv1 col-md-6 pull-left"> <span class="input-group-addon text-left"><div class="leftsidetextwidth">Police Station :</div></span>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Police Station"> 
                      </div>
                      <div class="clearfix"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="totalaligndiv">
            <div class="col-md-6" style="padding-left:0px;">
            <div class="block block-themed themed-asphalt">
                <div class="block-title"><h5>Annual Income From Sources</h5></div>
                    <div class="block-content full">
                        <div class="totalaligndiv">
                          <div class="input-group bmargindiv1 col-md-12 pull-left"><span class="input-group-addon text-left"><div class="leftsidetextwidth">BPL :</div></span>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="BPL"> 
                          </div>
                          <div class="input-group bmargindiv1 col-md-12 pull-left"><span class="input-group-addon text-left"><div class="leftsidetextwidth">Govt. Services :</div></span>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Govt. Services"> 
                          </div>
                          <div class="input-group bmargindiv1 col-md-12 pull-left"><span class="input-group-addon text-left"><div class="leftsidetextwidth">Business :</div></span>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Business"> 
                          </div>
                          <div class="input-group bmargindiv1 col-md-12 pull-left"> <span class="input-group-addon text-left"><div class="leftsidetextwidth">Land Property :</div></span>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Land Property"> 
                          </div>
                          <div class="input-group bmargindiv1 col-md-12 pull-left"> <span class="input-group-addon text-left"><div class="leftsidetextwidth">Others :</div></span>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Others">
                          </div>
                          <div class="input-group bmargindiv1 col-md-12 pull-left" style="height:55px;">
                          &nbsp; 
                          </div>
                          <div class="clearfix"></div>
                    </div>
                    </div>
            </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6" style="padding-right:0px;">
              <div class="block block-themed themed-asphalt">
                    <div class="block-title"><h5>Application Details</h5></div>
                    <div class="block-content full">
                        <div class="totalaligndiv">
                          <div class="input-group bmargindiv1 col-md-12 pull-left"><span class="input-group-addon text-left"><div class="leftsidetextwidth">Select Purpose :</div></span>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Select Purpose"> 
                          </div>
                          <div class="input-group bmargindiv1 col-md-12 pull-left"><span class="input-group-addon text-left"><div class="leftsidetextwidth">Amount Required :</div></span>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Amount Required"> 
                          </div>
                          <div>Has he/she received any assistance earlier from this fund</div>
                          <div class="input-group bmargindiv1 col-md-12 pull-left">
                          <span class="input-group-addon text-left"><div class="leftsidetextwidth">Status :</div></span>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Status"> 
                          </div>
                          <div class="input-group bmargindiv1 col-md-12 pull-left"> <span class="input-group-addon text-left"><div class="leftsidetextwidth">Prev. Receipt No. :</div></span>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Prev. Receipt No."> 
                          </div>
                          <div class="input-group bmargindiv1 col-md-12 pull-left"> <span class="input-group-addon text-left"><div class="leftsidetextwidth">Amount Received :</div></span>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Amount Received"> 
                          </div>
                          <div class="input-group bmargindiv1 col-md-12 pull-left"> <span class="input-group-addon text-left"><div class="leftsidetextwidth">Date of Received :</div></span>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Date of Received"> 
                          </div>
                          <div class="clearfix"></div>
                    </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="clearfix"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="tpaddingdiv1">
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <div class="text-center bpaddingdiv1"><img src="image/personsphoto.png" border="0" name="signature" height="140" class="borderblackdiv"></div>
                <div class="fontweightbolddiv fontssizediv3 text-center bpaddingdiv1">Deceased Photo</div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <div class="text-center bpaddingdiv1"><img src="image/personsphoto.png" border="0" name="signature" height="140" class="borderblackdiv"></div>
                <div class="fontweightbolddiv fontssizediv3 bpaddingdiv1 text-center">Donor Photo</div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <div class="text-center bpaddingdiv1"><img src="image/signaturetwo.jpg" border="0" name="signature" height="140" class="borderblackdiv"></div>
                <div class="fontweightbolddiv fontssizediv3 bpaddingdiv1 text-center">Donor Thumb</div>
            </div>
            <div class="clearfix"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    </div>
```

Check the above file I can access only values by @sdf but can not access value by @hcsy which i need.So please help me to fetch data by @hcsy object from db to this above template.My other related files are given below.

> scan_report.js.erb:

```
$("#hcsy_block").html("<%= escape_javascript (render 'hcsy_output_table',locals: "{hcsy: @hcsy }" ) %>");
$("#hcsy_block").slideDown(350);
```

> scan_report.html.erb:

```
<%= render 'hcsy_output_table',locals: "{hcsy: @hcsy }" %>
```

The _hcsy_output_table.html.erb will render on the home page within div id "hcsy_block".I can only access through @sdf object but i need also data using @hcsy object.Please help me to access data by @hcsy object and let me to know where i have done the mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the above you have this code in the home action:

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.html
  format.js
end
```

You have made the file `scan_report.js.erb` and in the action `scan_report` you have no code for the response in js. So from where does the AJAX request is sent and to which action it is sent. If it is sent to the `scan_report` action then try adding this:

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.js
end
```

If this is not the solution add up the details of the action to which the request is sent and also the code from where you send the request.